# Why requiring fails with dynamic symbols?

Tags: symbols

I just encountered this behavior of Emacs.

This works:

```
(require 'test)
```

But this doesn't

```
(require (make-symbol "test"))
```

Why is that and can I workaround it somehow?

Comment: maybe use `intern` instead of `make-symbol`? Why do you want `make-symbol`?

Comment: Oh, I just saw your answer. Can you please explain to me with simple words what's the big difference between these two?

Comment: `(equal 'test (intern "test"))` => t, `(equal 'test (make-symbol "test"))` => nil, `(equal (make-symbol "test") (make-symbol "test"))` => nil. A symbol is not a name, a symbol has a name.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use case that you have in mind for this?

Comment: I want to modulize my Emacs init sequence, because I use Emacs on different machines for different purposes. So I'm just going to have a 'module' directory where I put all my init files (for example dedicated init file for auto-complete, init file with python settings, GNU/Linux settings, Windows settings, etc) and load just the modules I need.

Comment: OK, this is my .emacs now, it looks very clean by me. Each piece of extra functionality is provided by automatically loaded modules. https://github.com/ydm/dotFiles/blob/master/emacs/_emacs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it looks like the symbol needs to be "interned". http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html

This works as expected:

```el
(require (intern "test"))
```

Comment: Unless you have a file named "test", you're going to get `(file-error "Cannot open load file" "test")`.